# Why does my Android HorizontalScrollView not scroll?

Tags: android, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView with a GridView inside of it. The GridView has a fixed number of columns (and items, controlled by its adapter) and fixed layout_width and a fixed layout_height. I played around with many properties of the GridView and the HorizontalScrollView, but the HorizontalScrollView will not scroll. Note that the root of my layout is a ScrollView (vertical)

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fuer_"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/medikament_"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_medikament"
                android:layout_column="1" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/medikament_erstellen"
                android:id="@+id/button_medikament_erstellen"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/verschreiber_"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_verschreiber"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/behandler_erstellen"
                android:id="@+id/button_behandler_erstellen"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridview"
                    android:layout_width="900dp"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:numColumns="9"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#ffffbc35">

                </GridView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView51"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/beginn_"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_beginn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:editable="false"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mode_radio_group"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="2">
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_immer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/iimmer"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_enddatum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/enddatum"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow56"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView53"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ende_"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_ende"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:editable="false"
                android:enabled="false" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my adapter:

```
public class MedikamentGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private long patientId;

public MedikamentGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
    this.patientId = prefs.getLong(Constants.SELECTED_PATIENT_ID, 1);
}

public MedikamentGridViewAdapter(Context context, long patientId) {
    this.context = context;
    this.patientId = patientId;
    this.prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_FILE, 0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 54;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // determine columns from position
    View view;
    int rest = position % 9;
    int row = position / 9;
    int column = rest;
    if(rest == 0){
        view = new TextView(context);
        ((TextView)view).setText("ABCDEFGHI");
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    } else {
        view = new EditText(context);
        ((EditText)view).setText(String.valueOf(row) + "," + String.valueOf(column));
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using gridview inside scrollview then you have to manage scrolling of both using touch events. If you only want grid in horizontal you can create horizontal grid view using Recyclerview https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html